# Protect SMS and Contact using password in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing an Android app that will protect SMS and Contact of user using password.

But how to really prevent other apps (that have SMS-relate permissions) from reading sms and contact?

I mean I need totally protect that data of user.

Any Idea or resource?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> But how to really prevent other apps (that have SMS-relate permissions) from reading sms and contact?

You don't, from an Android app.

> I need totally protect that data of user

You are welcome to download the Android source code, modify it to prevent any apps other than yours from accessing SMS or contacts (perhaps by upgrading the relevant Android permissions to a `signature` `protectionLevel`), compile your modified Android into a ROM mod, and deploy that ROM mod to whoever wants it.

Comment: Is that true? :(

So, when you create an app that supports protect sms by using password, will be useless? Because Viber can access sms also. => No protection here!

Comment: @Songokute: "Is that true?" -- you cannot interfere with other apps. You are welcome to create your own SMS client that stores its messages in its own private area (not the system SMS `ContentProvider`) and secures access to that data with a password. You are also welcome to create your own contacts client that stores contacts in its own private area (not the system `ContactsContract` `ContentProvider`) and secures access to that data with a password.